# Why rich popupPanel component of richfaces submits null value to managed beans?

Tags: jsf, popup, richfaces

I'm using rich:popupPanel component of richfaces 4.0 & jsf 2.0 which contains some form fields like name.address & contact also one a4j:commandButton "Save". The text fields are bind to managed bean properties like

```
<h:inputText size="25" maxlength="20" value="#{us.patient.lname}"/>
```

When I click on save button then add method of button is executed which prints value of textfield (i.e properties of beans). As textfield value is not empty, the value of textfield is not bind to property of beans. It gives null result why this happen only for popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `<rich:popupPanel>` we have to include `<h:form>` attribute.so when we click on button this form is submit and value are passes to beans.

Answer (score 1):

Do you render the `<rich:popupPanel>` after pressing the  `<a4j:commandButton>` ?

For example , suppose your popupPanel  has the id called `popup` ( `<rich:popupPanel id="popup">`) , you need to set the reRender attribute of the  `<a4j:commandButton>` to defines which JSF componet you want to update as a response on Ajax interaction. In your case , you should update your `<rich:popupPanel>` after pressing the save `<a4j:commandButton>` , so you should use:

`<a4j:commandButton value="Save" reRender="#{rich:clientId('popup')}" />`